# RadComboBox and RadTextbox not working

Tags: telerik, radcombobox, radtextbox

I am using VS2013 framework 4.5 and telerik version 2014.1.403.45

RadComboBox not showing the items on clicking on it. The defination is like this-

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="cmbjobType" runat="server" Skin="Web20" 
 EmptyMessage="--Please Select--">
<Items>                  
   <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="0" Text="Repair" />
   <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="1" Text="Additional" />
   <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="2" Text="Modify" />
   </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

RadTextBox also not working properly, the Empty message is not clearing on clicking on the textbox

```
 <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtProjTitle" EmptyMessage="Enter Project Title" CssClass="TextBox" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
```

and i face some more issues is this some version problem, please suggest.

Comment: Both controls are working on my side with your markup. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Please check that is there any JS in your page.

Comment: I found the problem, actually whenever i try to add the ajax control to the page the controls which are below this ajax controls are not functioning.
If i remove the ajax controls then other telerik works fine.But i want ajax control to be included, please help

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following to my master Page

```
 <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" AsyncPostBackTimeout="6000000" runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
                <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
                <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js"></asp:ScriptReference>

            </Scripts>
        </telerik:RadScriptManager
```

It might getting conflict with ToolScriptManager, once i removed these lines of COde , all my ajax and telerik controls worked as expected.